# Python Flask Log in con OAuth Google

Tags: html, python, google-oauth

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación en la que los usuarios se registran mediante una cuenta en los servicios de Google y Github. 
Ni siquiera puedo hacer que se registren por google, y mi mejor intento lo hice a partir de:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/29629536/6278712

El problema, es que mi html es mas complejo el cual es:

[html codigo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5LOY.png)
No entiendo como implementar la función login para que pueda interactuar con los tokens de google, así por ejemplo en la pagina oficial de Flask tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login_user(user)
        flask.flash('Logged in successfully.')
        next = flask.request.args.get('next')
        if not next_is_valid(next):
            return flask.abort(400)
        return flask.redirect(next or flask.url_for('index'))
    return flask.render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Pero, no deja claro donde se puede procesar los tokens de servicios auxiliares, como el de google por ejemplo.

Comment: Por favor, incluye el código del HTML, las imágenes no ayudan mucho y es más difícil ayudarte

Comment: Necesitas agregar detalles del _código actual_, no de código genérico copiado de internet. Es decir, del código con el que tienes problemas. De otro modo, ante la falta de detalles, la pregunta es __demasiado amplia__.